# Why am I getting a large discrepancy between theoretical and experimental Fermi energies for aluminium?

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, fermi-energy

I'm using a [Gouy balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouy_balance) to try and experimentally determine the susceptibility and Fermi energy of an aluminium rod. For the susceptibility, the value I've arrived at is $\chi = 2.0 \cdot 10^{-5}$, which seems to agree reasonably well with tabulated values for aluminium. I now want to use this result and the free electron model to obtain a value of the Fermi energy $E_F$ of the electron gas, using Kittel for reference. The relation between the susceptibility of a free electron gas and its Fermi temperature $T_F \equiv E_F/k_B$ is derived by Kittel as

\begin{equation} \tag{1} \label{chi}
   \chi = \frac{n\mu_B^2\mu_0}{k_BT_F} \Rightarrow E_F = \frac{n\mu_B^2\mu_0}{\chi}
\end{equation}

where $n = n_{e^-}$ is the concentration of electrons. If each Al atom contributes three electrons to the gas, it should mean that

$$ n_{e^-} = 3n_\mathrm{Al} = 3\frac{\rho_\mathrm{Al}}{m_\mathrm{Al}} $$

where $\rho_\mathrm{Al} = 2.7 \cdot 10^3$ kg/m$^3$ is the density of aluminium and $m_\mathrm{Al} = 26.98$ u is the atomic mass. Using these values along with my experimentally determined $\chi$ in Eq. \eqref{chi} I get that $E_F \approx 6.2$ eV. Now, Kittel also derives an expression for the Fermi energy of an electron gas as

\begin{equation} \tag{2} \label{teo}
   E_F = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m_\mathrm{e^-}} \bigg(\frac{3\pi^2N}{V} \bigg)^{2/3}
\end{equation}

where $N$ is the total number of electrons such that $N/V = n_{e^-}$ as defined above. Computing The Fermi energy using Eq. \eqref{teo} then yields the theoretical value $E_F \approx 11.66$ eV, in good agreement with Kittel's tabulated value for aluminium, but almost twice my experimentally obtained value.

Now, Kittel states that one has to take into account the diamagnetism of the ionic cores, band effects and interactions between electrons before comparing Eq. \eqref{chi} with experiment, but since the value of $\chi$ I've obtained seems to be approximately correct, I can't imagine that it is the issue here. I'm assuming that I have misinterpreted something, but I can't seem to figure out what. Why am I seeing such a large difference?

Edit: Apparently, the issue is that the free electron model does not offer an accurate description for Aluminium.